# ¿Como crear menus y sub-manus con php y mysqli de forma dinamica?

Tags: php, mysqli, menú

Quiero diseñar un menu de forma dinamica con php y msqli. Donde me aparece el menu y submenu. al drale click que me envie a una apgina que se llama productos. php y me despliegue los productos de mi menu. Y si hay un submenu que me despligue los sub-productos de mi categoria. Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$basedatos="menu";

//CREAR CONEXION

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$basedatos);

if(!$conn)
{
    die("Coneccion fallida". $mysqli_error());
} else
{
    echo "Coneccion exitosa\n";
}

function loop_array($array=array(), $parent_id=0){
    if(!empty($array[$parent_id])){
        echo'<ul>';
        foreach($array[$parent_id] as $items){

            if($items['parent_id']==3)
            {

            echo "<li><a href='productos.php?variable=".$items['name']."'/>".$items['name']."</a></li";
            }

            echo '<li><a href="'.$items['url'].'">';
            echo $items['name'];
            loop_array($array,$items['id']);
            echo '</li></a>';
        }
        echo'</ul>';
    }

}


function display_menus(){
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","menu");
    $query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM menus");
    $array=array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){

        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $array[$rows['parent_id']][]=$rows;     
        }
        loop_array($array);
    }

}  

?>
```

El problema es que me duplica el submenu. Un submenu sirve y el otro no.Es te es el archivo donde recibo la seleccion de productos.

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$basededatos="menu";

//CREAR CONEXION
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$basededatos);

if(!$conn)
{
    die("Coneccion fallida.". mysqli_error());
}
{
    echo "Coneccion exitosa. \n"."<br>";
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//REcIBIR VARIABLE
$var1=($_GET['variable']);
/*if(empty($var1)){
    header('Location:index.php');

}

/*
if (empty($var1))
{
    echo "VAriable vacia";
}
else
{
    echo "Vaiable con valor";   
}
*/

$sql = "SELECT id, modelo FROM productos WHERE parent_id='$var1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Modelo: ".$row["modelo"]."<br>";
    }}else
    {
        echo "Sin resultados";
    }

echo "Hola";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

En mi base de datos tengo dos. Una de los menus.

```
id name      parent_id url
1  home      0         index.php
2  products  0         producto.php 
3  bocina    1
4  rca       1
```

Y el de productos

```
id modelo    parent_id descripcion
1  ind-3br   3         bocina chica
2  ind-6br   4         rca largo
```

Ojala me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de lo que estás obteniendo ahora y otro ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener? Es que si no uno está obligado a interpretar todo tu código para luego tratar de adivinar la lógica que estás implementando. ¿Podrías explicar también por qué usas dos consultas en vez de una? Si tus tablas están relacionadas todo se puede obtener mediante una sola consulta.

Comment: Hola. Si claro. Obtengo lo siguiente

Comment: Obtengo lo siguiente: